# *Master in Java Programming* or *Master at Java Programming* - The Use of 'Master'

Tags: prepositions

When you master something, you master *in* that or *at* that?

> He's a master **in** Java Programming

Vs.

> He's a master **at** Java Programming

Note: Java programming is just an example and not something to explore or dig in further. I'm concerned with when you *master something*, you master *at* or *in* that?

Comment: I think it should be either *"He is a master ..."* or *"He has mastered ..."* As for the preposition, my gut feeling says *at* is better.

Comment: @DamkerngT. though I found examples (from authentic sources) without article, I must agree that putting it makes it better. Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot *of*:

> He's a master **of** Java Programming.

That's the preposition used in the famous idiom  [*Jack of all trades, master of none*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_of_all_trades,_master_of_none). It also seems to be the preposition of choice according the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20is%20a%20master%20of,he%20is%20a%20master%20in,he%20is%20a%20master%20at&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3):

[image]

As to your note:

> *Java programming is just an example and not something to explore or dig in further. I'm concerned with when you master something, you master* at *or* in *that*?

I believe there are some things that one can master, and one preposition will sound more natural than another. For example:

> James is a master in deceit.
> Dave is a master at forgery.

If – for some reason – a writer did not want to use *of*, then *at* seems to work a little better than *in* when referring to dextrous skills where you make something tangible (such as forgery, woodcarving, or quiltmaking), but *in* seems to work a little better than *at* for something more abstract (such as deceit, inspiration, or strategizing). There's no fixed rule about such matters, though, and prepositions tend to be very flexible in usage.

What would work best with "programming"? Probably *of*.

Comment: Oh, I completely overlooked it! Noteworthy is after *of* there's *at*. +1 for this wonderful answer :)

Comment: What you think of this? You master *in* **doing** something and you master *at* **something**? This is my thinking looking at user3169's answer.

Comment: Or you simply master something. _He is a master Java programmer; she is a master safecracker_: no preposition required.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what the *something* is. In the case of skills or occupations:

> He's a master **in** Java Programming
>
> He's a master **in** electrical engineering.

On the other hand, in the case of actions or activities:

> He's a master **at** flying kites.
>
> He's a master **at** racing cars.

Sorry I can't give a technical reason though.

Comment: Aw, this reminds me this - **he's a master in/at marketing** - a skill as well as action :( now *at* or *in*? Thanks for the input though.

Comment: "He's a master *in* marketing" if you are referring to his occupation or training. "He's a master *at* marketing" if he goes out and actually does some "marketing". Such as "He's a master *at* selling books."

Comment: Yes, this sounds logical, I agree to this answer. For better clarification, I asked J.R. this as well. You master *in* **doing** something but you master *at* **something** this is what we mean, don't we?